# Used Change Address Tool in Search Console but Google still displays our old domain

Tags: google-search-console

We have used Google Search Consols, Change Address tool , we change our domain to .org from .net, and made the correct 301 redirectes in the website,

after 2 days Google search displayed our new domain in Search Results .org, and in the next day, it retruned show the old website, .net, I didn't figure out the problem, the site map was missing in the new domain, and I added it.

I want the Google Search to show only the new domain in search results,
What could be the problem? How can we solve it?

Comment: Search engines are not real time. It can take weeks or even months for the change to take effect.

Comment: @closetnoc yep you are right, but sometimes  we can do something to make the process faster,

Comment: Not really. Search engines go at their own pace regardless of what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following and it should fix it.

1. Make sure you set 301 redirect from your .net domain to .org domain.
2. In Google Webmaster, add your new .org domain and load XML sitemap of .org domain.
3. In your old domain (.net) you don't need to do anything apart from setting proper 301 redirect.

Note: For few days to a week or so you may notice old domain in the search result and slowly it will go off.

Regarding result getting mixed, don't worry as it will take bit of time to change the index and as long as 301 redirect is set properly you don't need to worry.

Comment: thanks very much, I only added a sitemap for the olde website, and didn't add the sitemap of the old website, now  for the most important key word , google shows our new domain, but from many keywords it still shows the old url, I will do my best fetch as google for those pages, and wait for the reusults